# checking if user account status has changed and logging them out if its been set to inactive by admin in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I want to know if there is a proper method of going about say I am a admin on my site and a user is browsing in the site already logged in and I go in and set their account status to 2 (In Active)

```
1 = Active
2 = In Active
3 = Terminated
```

Laravel doesn't automatically check so I would need to create, I am guessing middleware, but I am unsure on how to go about writing the code for my 2 different guards (admin and web). With my login function I use laravel's documentation for checking if status is equal to 1 so I already don't have to worry about them logging in again but if their session is already started I need to end it and I am guessing run a middleware on every HTTP request check and see if both or just 1 guard is in use and then check its status. if its active then do nothing, if its set to In Active(2) or Terminated(3) then we need to log them out. Could anyone give me a start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally haven't tried this, but there's always a first time. You are on the right path of putting this code in a middleware.

```
php artisan make:middleware CheckUserStatus
```

Add the newly created middle to your **app/Http/kernel.php**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    .
    .
    'status' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckUserStatusMiddleware::class
]
```

Inside your CheckUserStatusMiddleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $redirectToRoute = null)
{
    if ($request->user() && $request->user()->status != 1) {
        auth()->logout();
        return abort(403, 'Your status is not active anymore.');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Lastly, add the middleware to your route call

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->middleware('status');
```

Comment: I like what you did so far and i can understand it. Is there anyway that i could have it added to the HTTP middleware to run on each page request and use guards to check if both admin and user sessions are logged in?

Comment: I am not seeing guards being used here but i'm not sure if $request->user() will give the one that the route is accessing